# JQuery does not happen with this variable...?

Tags: jquery, window

I am trying to make this action happen when the width of the window is smaller than 490 px. But theJavaScript does not work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 490) {
        $("section div share").click(function () {
            $("sharebuttons").slideToggle('slow')
        });
    } else {
        $("section div share").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            //I would like the action would not happen when the window px are bigger than 490
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The condition `$('window').width() < 490` does not work. It works with `$('window')` replaced by `$(window)`. `window` is a Javascript - object and not a selector to find something in your document - tree.  So, I guess that jQuery does not recognize it when passing it as string.

Additionally, I think you have to revise your [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp). If you want to match an element with ID `share` the token in the selector has to be `#share`. If you want to match an element with class `share` the token in the selector has to be `.share`.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I took off the "", however the jquery still does not work... :/

Comment: I successfully tried it in jsfiddle with if- and else-block replaced by alert.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have seen many posts with this working with alerts and changing css/colours. Weird it does not work with these parameters.